# cocoa: why for-each is faster than for loop?

Tags: cocoa, for-loop

My application read all people in contact in two ways:

for-loop:

```
    CFAbsoluteTime startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent ();
    long count = macContact.addressBook.people.count;
    for(int i=0;i<count;++i){
        ABPerson *person = [macContact.addressBook.people objectAtIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"%@",person);
    }
    NSLog(@"%f",CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startTime);
```

for-each

```
    CFAbsoluteTime startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent ();
    for(ABPerson *person in macContact.addressBook.people){
        NSLog(@"%@",person);
    }
    NSLog(@"%f",CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startTime);
```

for-each only took 4 seconds to enumerate 5000 people in addressBook, while for-loop took 10 minutes to do the same job.

I want to know why there is a huge difference in performance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference in performance almost certainly has to do with the `macContact.addressBook.people` part. You're calling that every single time through the for loop but only once with the for-each loop. I'm guessing either the `addressBook` or the `people` properties are not returning cached data but rather new data every time.

Try using

```
NSArray *people = macContact.addressBook.people;
for (int i = 0; i < [people count]; i++) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [people objectAtIndex:i];
}
```

You'll probably find the performance is very similar again.

---

That said, for-each is faster than for in general. The reason is because a for loop invokes a method send on every single pass through the loop (`-objectAtIndex:`), whereas for-each can fetch the objects much more efficiently by grabbing them in large batches.

In more recent versions of the OS you can go a step further and use a block-based enumeration method. This looks like

```
[macContact.addressBook.people enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL stop){
    NSLog(@"%@", obj);
}];
```

For NSArrays this should have very similar performance to a for-each loop. For other data structures such as dictionaries this style can be faster because it can fetch the value along with the key (whereas a for-each only gives you the key and requires you to use a message send to get the value).